# "No rule to make target '../output/.br-external.mk" running Buildroot in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, buildroot

I'm trying to run Buildroot in an Azue pipeline and have a problem.  I'm executing a Bash task in a Ubuntu-22.04 image with the commands:

```
make my_defconfig
make
```

the command I would normally use to run my build.  When the are executed inside a pipeline, the first command fails:

```
make my_defconfig
make: *** No rule to make target '/home/vsts/work/1/s/output/.br-external.mk'.  Stop.
```

and the following make command dies. I have verified that my commands are being run from the right directory (the root directory for my Buildroot files).

I added "ls" and a "find" commands to my pipeline script and that file is definitely nowhere to be found in my Buildroot tree when my Pipeline job runs. It is also no present in my Buildroot tree when I first clone my Buildroot tree from my git repository.  It IS there after I run    `make my_defconfig`.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You can add `ls` command in your bash task to list and check the files in the folder.  By the way, can you share more details to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I've actually done that but didn't include that output in my post.  I'll edit it and include additional details. Thansk.

Answer (score 0):

So after hitting this problem with a hammer many times, I finally found the solution. I added the following two command to my pipeline script before my `make my_defconfig`, executed from the Buildroot root directory:

```
mkdir output
touch output/.br-external.mk
```

After that, things started working...almost.  Other issues popped up that prevented the build from finishing successfully.  For the next problem, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77632448/buildroot-error-in-azure-pipeline-communicate-h20944-note-expected-struct) post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the script that generates `.br-external.mk` is not working. To debug it, you can run it manually and with extra debug (i.e. add a command line to run it):

```
/bin/bash -x support/scripts/br2-external -m -o 'output/.br-external.mk' ${BR2_EXTERNAL}
```

I suspect `BR2_EXTERNAL` is pointing to something that is not a valid external, and the validation fails to produce an error message like it should.

By the way, `.br-external.mk` was renamed to `.br2-external.mk` four years ago, so you're using a very old version of Buildroot. In fact, if you're using something older than [commit c5fa9308](https://gitlab.com/buildroot.org/buildroot/-/commit/c5fa9308ea4e3810a7f7d9d0df75cbf090c414c4) (i.e. 2017.02 or older), then error reporting for BR2_EXTERNAL was not working at all and you'd have this issue.