# Buildroot error in Azure Pipeline: communicate.h:209:44: note: expected 'struct stat64 *' but argument is of type 'struct stat *'

Tags: azure-pipelines, buildroot

I've had more problems trying to run Buildroot in an Azure Pipeline.  I'm using a Ubuntu 22.04 with gcc 9.5. I am running Buildroot from the root directory of my Buildroot installation (my repository). I'm running under the default Ubuntu pipeline user, which is vsts. I'm running a bash script, which looks like this:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 90 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9
mkdir output
touch output/.br-external.mk
make my_defconfig
make
```

When I run `make` (after `make my_defconfig`) I see a lot of warnings that I don't see when building on my local Ubuntu 22.04 box with gcc 9.4, but when the build hits libfakeroot.c, it generates a bunch of errors and dies due to problems in communicate.h.  The number of warnings and errors are too much to show here so I'll only show a snippet of the errors at the end of the build:

```
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~
fakerootconfig.h:9:43: note: in definition of macro 'NEXT_STAT64'
    9 | #define NEXT_STAT64(a,b,c) next___xstat64(a,b,c)
      |                                           ^
libfakeroot.c:1853:5: note: in expansion of macro 'INT_NEXT_STAT'
 1853 |   r=INT_NEXT_STAT(path, &st);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
libfakeroot.c: In function 'lremovexattr':
libfakeroot.c:100:42: error: '_STAT_VER' undeclared (first use in this function)
  100 | #define INT_NEXT_LSTAT(a,b) NEXT_LSTAT64(_STAT_VER,a,b)
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~
fakerootconfig.h:13:45: note: in definition of macro 'NEXT_LSTAT64'
   13 | #define NEXT_LSTAT64(a,b,c) next___lxstat64(a,b,c)
      |                                             ^
libfakeroot.c:1874:5: note: in expansion of macro 'INT_NEXT_LSTAT'
 1874 |   r=INT_NEXT_LSTAT(path, &st);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libfakeroot.c: In function 'fremovexattr':
libfakeroot.c:101:42: error: '_STAT_VER' undeclared (first use in this function)
  101 | #define INT_NEXT_FSTAT(a,b) NEXT_FSTAT64(_STAT_VER,a,b)
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~
fakerootconfig.h:11:45: note: in definition of macro 'NEXT_FSTAT64'
   11 | #define NEXT_FSTAT64(a,b,c) next___fxstat64(a,b,c)
      |                                             ^
libfakeroot.c:1895:5: note: in expansion of macro 'INT_NEXT_FSTAT'
 1895 |   r=INT_NEXT_FSTAT(fd, &st);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libfakeroot.c: In function 'fts_read':
libfakeroot.c:1959:22: warning: passing argument 1 of 'send_get_stat64' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1959 |     SEND_GET_STAT64(r->fts_statp, _STAT_VER);
      |                     ~^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                      |
      |                      struct stat *
libfakeroot.c:89:46: note: in definition of macro 'SEND_GET_STAT64'
   89 | #define SEND_GET_STAT64(a,b) send_get_stat64(a)
      |                                              ^
In file included from libfakeroot.c:60:
communicate.h:209:44: note: expected 'struct stat64 *' but argument is of type 'struct stat *'
  209 | extern void send_get_stat64(struct stat64 *buf);
      |                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
libfakeroot.c: In function 'fts_children':
libfakeroot.c:1982:24: warning: passing argument 1 of 'send_get_stat64' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1982 |       SEND_GET_STAT64(r->fts_statp, _STAT_VER);
      |                       ~^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                        |
      |                        struct stat *
libfakeroot.c:89:46: note: in definition of macro 'SEND_GET_STAT64'
   89 | #define SEND_GET_STAT64(a,b) send_get_stat64(a)
      |                                              ^
In file included from libfakeroot.c:60:
communicate.h:209:44: note: expected 'struct stat64 *' but argument is of type 'struct stat *'
  209 | extern void send_get_stat64(struct stat64 *buf);
      |                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
make[3]: *** [Makefile:642: libfakeroot.lo] Error 1
```

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: `_STAT_VER` _should_ be defined earlier in libfakeroot.c, so this error is really surprising. The definition is under various other define's, however, but at least `__linux__` should really be defined!

Comment: Your build can run locally, but not in the pipeline. The possible difference is the software version and running account. In addition, you can also consider creating a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/linux-agent?view=azure-devops) locally and check if it works.